# Problem with reading an array with multiple types in Fortran

Tags: arrays, input, types, fortran

I am trying to read in an array from a text file in Fortran. It reads the first entry ok, but then when it goes round for the next iteration of the loop it returns an error

> At line 8 of file test.f (unit = 1, file = 'DATA.inp')
> Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 2 of list input

At first I thought it was because the first number is an integer not real or float number, however, I changed the first number in each line in DATA.inp to floating number and it comes up with the same error.

The reduced code is as follows:

```
        PROGRAM test
           IMPLICIT NONE 
           REAL INP(8,1000)
           REAL INP1(1000), INP2(1000)
           INTEGER i, j
           OPEN(1,FILE='DATA.inp', STATUS='OLD')
           i=1
   10      READ(1,*,END=100)(INP(j,i), j=1,8)
           INP1(i) = INP(1,i)
           INP2(i) = INP(2,i)
           WRITE(*,*)INP1(i)
           WRITE(*,*)INP2(i)
           i=i+1
           GOTO 10
  100      CONTINUE     
        END PROGRAM
```

Data in the DATA.inp file

```
1, 10., 5., 400., 1.04, 30., 9., 10.
2, 2O., 15., 350., 1.08, 32., 11., 11.
3, 30., 25., 220., 1.02, 36., 11., 12.
4, 40., 35., 250., 1.03, 35., 19., 15.
5, 50., 45., 325., 1.10, 40., 22., 18.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the issue with your original data set, but assuming that the `DATA.inp` file you shared is correct, you are not passing a real number into the program. The second line and second row of your data contains the *letter* `O` and not the *number* `0`.

You'll notice that the character is missing the little dot in the center ^_^

```
2O. vs 20.
```

EDIT:

fwiw, I found the error quickly by reading your data directly into an array and found the error message to be much more helpful. Specifically:

```
program test
  implicit none
  real, dimension(8,5) :: array1, array2

  open(unit = 1, file = 'DATA.inp')
  read(1,*) array1
end program test
```

which yields the helpful error

```
At line 6 of file so.f90 (unit = 1, file = 'DATA.inp')
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 10 of list input

Error termination. Backtrace:
...
```

Comment: I feel rather stupid now, do you know how long I have been trying to debug this issue! Thank you.

Comment: @OB1 No worries. Definitely understand staring at the screen for too long. fwiw, I noticed the error because I tried to read your data into an array directly which spit out the very helpful error `bad real number in item 10 of list input`.

Comment: @OB1 The closeness of 0 and o at the keyboard certainly does not help. On some keyboard layouts one also needs to press Shift to get the numbers so one can easily type O instead of 0.